# Is there a portable way to generate a true random globally unique identifier (guid)?

Tags: random, guid

I am looking for an utility to generate a true random globally unique identifier (guid) in order to copy and paste the generated guid in source code.

Many utilities exist that are based on some built-in guid generator. These generators may include network card MAC addresses, the system clock, pseudo random sequences and more.

The generator must however be true random. This is because of my firm belief that any attempt to reduce the probability of guid collisions will actually increase this probability.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to find an approach using something like white noise sampling built in the CPU.

Not finding a portable solution I ended up with querying [random.org](http://www.random.org), trusting that they do a good job.

A [Windows commandline utility](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bGXSJBOBO2YfegbfIPUw5AbJ0L9sGWjv/view?usp=sharing) is enclosed that queries random.org over HTTP, assembles a true random guid, and copies the guid to the clipboard.

```
getguid
Guid d9cc9db3-dd4a-b05a-44ac-679b7dbefcf0 copied to the clipboard.
Quota remaining at random.org: 999872 bits.
Press enter.
```

Your free quota at random.org will be 1000000 bits per day; consuming 128 bit per requested quid.

The zip contains the executable and the source code for use in Visual Studio 2015 or 2017.

Note that the utility generates true random bits for all 128 bits of the guid. This is a **violation** of the standard. For example [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) describes that the guid should spend a few bits to indicate the guid type. The utility however prefers to be entirely random in order to maximize the range of guids and hopefully to minimize the probability of collisions.